# Change colour of text foreground based on background color input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an input element which allows users to set the background colour of the input element.

When the user sets the background colour of the input element, I want the text in the input element to be a contrasting colour to the original colour.

For example: The user inputs "black" as the input background colour; then the text colour of the input will be white. However if the user inputs "white" as the input colour, the text colour would be black. (There are more cases than just black or white.)

How would I achieve this? I know that you can use another element on top of a background and set mix-blend-mode, but I don't want to because that would remove the point of the input.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using a simple text-shadow to outline the text so that it appears when on top of any color?

Comment: That's alright but not ideal :3 thanks for the suggestion tho

Comment: Yea, it's definitely the ugly way to go :)  For anybody reading this in the future that may wonder what I meant here's [text outline with text-shadow](https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/agdh87uo/) and because I'm procrastinating a basic transparent container [way to keep text readable](https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/jqkcm8xy/) (though not always easy on the eyes)

Comment: +1 for the fiddle :) that would be good if it was just text, but this is v specific to an <input> element specifically and its internal background, which is a different kettle of fish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could calculate if black or white would have a higher contrast with the color given by the user based on the hexadecimal value of the color.

This link goes into detail on two ways to do this calculation.
https://24ways.org/2010/calculating-color-contrast/

Comment: I'll give it a shot... tho i want as few SLOC as possible. (Also the colours might not always be hex-they can be css named as well.